# How do I use get_media_file() in the latest Quickly?

Tags: python, application-development, quickly

I am writing a project with Quickly and GTK 3 and I want to use the `get_media_file()` helper so I can load an icon in my *data/media* directory.

I can't see how I use `get_media_file()` with the latest quickly; it looks like the Quickly helpers have changed.

Can anyone provide me with some sample code of how this works?

Answer (score 5):

Tell me if by 'latest' you don't mean the one that ships with 11.10, but this is how to use the function here:

```
>>> from hello_lib.helpers import get_media_file
>>> get_media_file("hello.svg")
file:////home/stefano/hello/data/media/hello.svg
```

"hello.svg" can be any fragment of a path (like `../media/hello.svg` or `stuff/hello.svg`). I.e. `get_media_file(f)` is the equivalent of

```
"file://" + os.path.join(get_data_path(), "media", f)
```

And `get_data_path()` will return `/home/stefano/hello/data`.

These functions are defined in `hello/hello_lib/helpers.py` and `hello/hello_lib/helloconfig.py`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you just give it the name of the file in your *data/media* directory.

For example, if you want *data/media/foo.png*, you just call `get_media_file('foo.png')`.  This will return a *file:///* URI of the absolute path to *foo.png*.